# Подсветка элемента меню, при скролле страницы до определенного места( например section id="one")

Tags: menu, navigation

Я нашел скрипты и они вроде работают. Но в консоле много ошибок. Посмотрите пожалуйста что можно поправить в скрипте, может покороче как то сделать их
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```js
 function onScroll(event) {
            var scrollPos = $(document).scrollTop();
            $('.top_menu a').each(function() {
                var currLink = $(this);
                var refElement = $(currLink.attr("href"));
                if (refElement.position().top <= scrollPos && refElement.position().top + refElement.height() > scrollPos) {
                    $('.top_menu ul li a').removeClass("active_menu");
                    currLink.addClass("active_menu");
                } else {
                    currLink.removeClass("active_menu");
                }
            });
        }
//var menu_selector = ".dot-nav"; 

$(document).ready(function () {

$(document).on("scroll", onScroll);

$("a[href^=#]").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(document).off("scroll");
    $(menu_selector + " a.active").removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");
    var hash = $(this).attr("href");
    var target = $(hash);
    $("html, body").animate({
        scrollTop: target.offset().top
    }, 500, function(){
        window.location.hash = hash;
        $(document).on("scroll", onScroll);
    });

});
});
```

```css
header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    margin-top: 2.5rem;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: #ccc;
}
section{
    min-height: 400px;
    border: 1px solid brown;
    margin: 20px auto;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 5px 5px gray;
    box-shadow: 0 5px 5px gray;
    padding: 0 10px;
}
.top_menu ul {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-pack: center;
    -ms-flex-pack: center;
    justify-content: center;
    position: fixed;
  top: 60px;
  
}
.top_menu li{
    list-style: none;
  margin: 0 30px;
}
.active_menu{
    background: rgba(0, 200, 100, .8);
    color: red;
    padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header>
    <h1>Веб на практике</h1>
    <nav class="top_menu">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#one" class="active_menu">Section 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#two">Section 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#three">Section 3</a></li>

              <li><a href="tel:+4917681438203" class="ui-link-inherit pfone">+49 176 814 38 203</a></li>
                        <li><a href="http://www.instagram.com/" target="_blank" class="cam">
                        <i class="fab fa-instagram"></i>
                    </a></li>
                        <li><a href="http://vk.com/" target="_blank" class="vk">
                        <i class="fab fa-vk"></i>
                    </a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</header>
<main>
    <section id="one">
        <h3>Section 1</h3>
    </section>
    <section id="two">
        <h3>Section 2</h3>
    </section>
    <section id="three">
        <h3><a href="https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors">Section 3</a></h3>
        <div class="up"><i class="fas fa-chevron-circle-up"></i></div>
    </section>
</main>
```

Answer (score 0):

У вас ошибка в строке:

```
$("a[href^=#]").click(function(e){
```

"#" надо взять в ковычки

```
$("a[href^='#']").click(function(e){
```

Comment: Спасибо! Проблемы не решает, правда. Работает и так и так нормально, но куча ошибок в консоле

Comment: У меня нет не одной ошибки в консоли. Хотя полностью скопировал ваш код и исправил только эту ошибку. Скорее всего у вас ошибки в другом месте.

Comment: Да точно ошибок нет. Я сюда урезанный код html вставил. Ругается вот на эти ссылки:     
<li><a href="tel:+4917681438203" class="ui-link-inherit pfone">+49 176 814 38 203</a></li>
                            <li><a href="http://www.instagram.com/" target="_blank" class="cam">
                            <i class="fab fa-instagram"></i>
                        </a></li>
                            <li><a href="http://vk.com/" target="_blank" class="vk">
                            <i class="fab fa-vk"></i>
                        </a></li>

Comment: Добавьте класс всем ссылкам которые соответствуют section. Пример: <a href="#two" class="nav-item">Section 2</a> И в скрипте $('.top_menu a.nav-item').. В 3-ей строке. Хотя .top_menu можно вовсе убрать.

Comment: У вас ещё была ошибка при клике. Полный вариант  https://jsfiddle.net/Lxua59jv/